# Python - Flask SQLAlchemy App not running - "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I was trying to learn, SQLAlchemey.
I copied code from a tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlalchemy.htm

It had an indentation error, so I fixed it. Furthermore, I added `run(use_reloader=False)` because it wasn't loading. But now it shows:

```
    This site can’t be reached The webpage at http://127.0.0.1:6000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_UNSAFE_PORT
```

in the browser.

The complete code is

```
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///students.sqlite3'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "random string"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class students(db.Model):
   id = db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(100))
   city = db.Column(db.String(50))
   addr = db.Column(db.String(200)) 
   pin = db.Column(db.String(10))

   def __init__(self, name, city, addr,pin):
       self.name = name
       self.city = city
       self.addr = addr
       self.pin = pin

@app.route('/')
def show_all():
   return render_template('show_all.html', students = students.query.all() )

@app.route('/new', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def new():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      if not request.form['name'] or not request.form['city'] or not request.form['addr']:
         flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')
      else:
         student = students(request.form['name'], request.form['city'],
            request.form['addr'], request.form['pin'])

         db.session.add(student)
         db.session.commit()
         flash('Record was successfully added')
         return redirect(url_for('show_all'))
   return render_template('new.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   db.create_all()
   app.run(port=6000, use_reloader=False, debug = True)
```

Comment: @BilalAliJafri:  **Do not advice to use 0.0.0.0** without explaining the security implications! They are connecting to localhost, the default host, and their Flask server does not need to be visible to the rest of their network.

Comment: @BilalAliJafri: if someone does this on a public network, they open themselves to possible security issues, including getting their machine hacked. The Werkzeug WSGI server is not battle-hardened, and when running in debug mode there is the possibility to bypass the simple PIN protection and allow for arbitrary Pythno code execution on your machine.

Comment: As such I've deleted your comment. Please don't ask people to open themselves up to such risks again. When running a Flask development server, keep it local.

Comment: with @MartijnPieters comment, use `wsgiref` not flask or etc.Do not use any applications such as flask or dijango without learning the WSGI application.

Comment: @dsgdfg: the whole point of `app.run()` is to give you a local server to develop with. *That's fine*. They are not trying to access this from anything but their own machine.

Answer (score -1):

Try to visit `http://localhost:5000/` since that is the default port flask is on

Comment: `app.run(port=6000, ...)` sets the port, it is no longer running on the default port.